# Pattern with alternative heads

Tags: pattern-matching

This works:

```
f[pattern : {_Integer ..} | Verbatim[Except]@{_Integer ..}] := "sneed"
{f[{1, 2, 3}], f[Except@{1, 2, 3}]}
(* {"sneed", "sneed"} *)
```

But what if instead of `{_Integer..}` it's a longer expression that I'd rather not repeat?

This also works:

```
g[pattern : Identity@{_Integer ..}] := "sneed"
g[{1, 2, 3}]
(* "sneed" *)
```

So I figured this should do the trick:

```
h[pattern : (Identity | Verbatim[Except])@{_Integer ..}] := "sneed"
{h[{1, 2, 3}], h[Except@{1, 2, 3}]}
(* {h[{1, 2, 3}], "sneed"} *)
```

Why does one of them not evaluate? How can I make it work?

Comment: You could do this: `h[pattern : # | Verbatim[Except][#] &@{_Integer ..}] := "sneed"`, which would still expand and repeat things at definition-time, expanding the definition, but at least you don't have to do that manually.

Comment: Similar to @LeonidShifrin's recommendation: `With[{complex = {_Integer ..}},
 h[pattern : complex | Verbatim[Except][complex]] := "sneed"]`